# how to send data from UIViewController to UITabBarControllers first tab in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

First login screen. after login I am receiving JSON data i parsed that data.know i need to send that data to UITabBarControllers first viewcontroller in that viewcontroller I placed labels. I need to fill that labels with this data

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender:AnyObject!)
    {
        if (segue.identifier == "first")
        {

    var svc = segue.destinationViewController as Vc1;
             svc.toPass  = name
            svc.toPass1 = pid
            svc.toPass2 = sex
            svc.toPass3 = dob
            svc.toPass4 = lastvisit
            svc.toPass5 = height
            svc.toPass6 = pulse
            svc.toPass7 = respiration
            svc.toPass8 = temp
            svc.toPass9 = sysbp
            svc.toPass10 = dysbp
            svc.toPass11 = weight
            svc.toPass12 = medicine
            svc.toPass13 = date
            svc.toPass14 = dosage
            svc.toPass15 = drugclass
            svc.toPass16 = duration
            svc.toPass17 = route
            svc.toPass18 = frequency
            svc.toPass19 = drnote
            svc.toPass20 = con_dr
```

Comment: What is toPass, toPass1 in your controller. Are these properties? And what is the issue you are facing. your code is not complete.

Comment: topass is a string variable  present in destination viewcontroller.   my problem is i need to pass the data to destination viewcontroller that is present in tabbarcontroller

Comment: Please edit your code and display the complete function prepareForSegue

Comment: just tell me how to send data from viewcontroller to tabbarcontrollers(first viewcontroller) in swift.

Comment: set a userdefaults i dont know swift or else i have given the code . find for userdefaults and you will able to do so

Comment: no idea what u r saying

Comment: tell me with some code please

Comment: in .h file

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {
UITabBarController *mainTabBarController;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *mainTabBarController;
-(IBAction) goToRegistrationPage;

in .m file

-(IBAction) goToRegistrationPage {
 mainTabBarController.selectedIndex=3;
}

Comment: need in swift not objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are segueing to a tabBarController, the destination VC will be a `UITabBarController`.  You can access the first view controller using the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` property:

```
let tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController
let svc = tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as Vc1
```

Comment: @Jassi Thanks. vooo It's worth looking at Jassi's repository as there are several ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: @vooo: Please accept my answer so that it can help others to quickly look which is the code that is working absolutely fine.

Comment: super jassi  really happy with ur answer thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code at this repository. Let me know if any help needed.

https://github.com/jassionly4u/UITabBarController-Swift