# pass data from view controller to tabController childs

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have a main view controller which has the following tuple:

```
var textsForTabs  = (tab1: "this is tab one text", tab2 : "this is tab 2 text")
```

from the main view controller i want this data to pass to a **tab controller** with 2 childs: tab 1 and tab 2 which have labels on them, the first tab should show in it's label the text from textsForTabs.tab1 and the second textsForTabs.tab2.

What are my options here and the best practice?

I tried to instantiate the tabbarcontroller and in it, get the first view controller and assign the value from the tupple to an instance variable, later to be used when view is being shown: like so:

```
let tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as UITabBarController
let ftc = tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as firstTabController
let stc = tabBarController.viewControllers![1] as secondTabController
ftc.setLabelTxt(textsForTab.tab1)
stc.setLabelTxt(textsForTab.tab2)
```

I got that from here:

[how to send data from UIViewController to UITabBarControllers first tab in swift ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271796/how-to-send-data-from-uiviewcontroller-to-uitabbarcontrollers-first-tab-in-swift)

But i read somewhere this is hacky, what are my other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to set the label txt when `viewDidLoad` is called for both `firstTabController` and `secondTabController`

Here an example for firstTabController :

```
class FirstTabController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController as? MyCustomTabBarController {
        self.setLabelTxt(tabBarController.textsForTabs.tab1)
      }
    }
    ...
}
```